# Kryo custom Serilization class with byte[] sent over Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, kryo

I am trying to serialize a class with Kryo and send it via Apache Kafka. The object that I am serializing has a byte[] as a field in the class. Serializing the object works fine, but I run into trouble when I try and de-serialize it using the read method. I always get an array out of bounds exception : -2 .

Below is my Data object class pojo and my custom serializer

```
public class Data {
  int dataSize;
  byte[] data;
}

public class DataSerializer extends Serializer<Data.class> {

 public void write (Kryo kryo, Output output, Data object) {
    output.writeInt(object.getDataSize());
    output.writeBytes(object.getData());
}

public Data read (Kryo kryo, Input input, Class<Data> type) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setDataSize = input.readInt();
    data.setData = input.readBytes(data.getDataSize());
    return data;
}
```

}

There is very little documentation on the readBytes() and writeBytes() usage. Am I doing this correctly?